# How could I make a viewing function for a simple game in Python?

Tags: python, game-physics, game-development

I'm working on creating a simple game in Python, just to get used to Python and get better at using it. Just so that the question that I have is understandable, I'll explain what the important parts of the game are. Basically, a character is in a 2d grid that can be up to 10x10 squares. The character moves around these squares doing various things. Each square can have a wall on any side. For example, "Square 1" might have walls on the north and west sides. The character can't move or see through these walls. The game has no graphics, so how could I create a function that would return which squares are visible, partially visible, or not visible based on the location of the character and the walls of squares surrounding him? Right now the squares are stored in a dictionary with more nested dictionaries, each square in the dictionary having more dictionaries that store values such as "walls" or "coordinates." Here is an example of one of the squares in that dictionary (stored in a json file):

```
{"square 1": {"items": [], "description": "This square has walls on the west and south sides", "coordinates": [0, 0], "walls": ["west", "south"]}
```

Obviously, this dictionary could be changed to a list of lists (for more easy coordinates) or another more useful form. I've added a picture to visualize it easier (the walls are the darker lines). From any square within this room, using the character's coords, I need a viewing function that would return which other squares the character could see, or partially see (partially see meaning that approximately only half of the square is visible).

[image: A helpful picture: the darkened borders are walls, coords on the sides.]

[image]

In the second picture, the large green dot is the character at (2, 2). The red lines represent his line of sight, and where it ends at a wall. I think that the solution to this problem might have to do with using these lines, but I'm not sure how this could be implemented in Python. The blue dots are in squares that are fully visible, and the yellow dots are in squares that are partially visible (meaning that about half of the square is visible). The scribbled out areas are just where a wall blocks the character's line of sight.

I know that the Stack Overflow community comes down pretty hard on anyone who asks questions without doing research, but believe me, I've done a lot of research and can't figure out a way to solve this problem. I would guess that it probably has something to do with the "lines of sight" that can be blocked, but I don't know how to do this Python. Any help or ideas to direct me in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: It would help if you show an example of how the dictionary and the code you have tried. Also, what does it mean _partially visible_?

Comment: Let's say this were a tabletop game and you are writing instructions for it, how would you formally explain what defines visible, partially visible, or not visible squares based on the location of the character?

Comment: Not researching questions is indeed a big issue here and I am glad that you took the time to research, but I do feel that this "simple" game isn't quite simple enough considering you're new to Python. This question isn't particularly *difficult* to solve, but it does involve a lot of complexity and it would be much more approachable if you had a better foundation in programming. You said your goal is to get used to Python, but I don't think you would learn anything if someone just told you what to do. I suggest trying to make an even simpler game first and coming back to this project later.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly I updated the question. The tabletop game is definitely an interesting way to look at it; I would probably define visible using a ruler to measure a line of sight, but I don't know how to apply that with Python. What concept or module in Python could be used to accomplish this? I'm ready and willing to do the research, I just don't know where to look, so if you could point me in the right direction that would be great. Would it possibly have something to do with vectors?

Comment: @SimonUnderwood I'm not completely new to Python, just not especially experienced yet. I've completed a basic course, and I figure that the best way to learn would just be to ask questions, and be persistent with figuring things out. I'm not asking for some one to just write the code for me, I think I just need the general idea of what to do and I can figure it out. Thanks for the suggestion, I definitely plan on increase my skills other ways as well, not just this game.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how exactly you've decided to structure your game objects, nor do I know what you mean by squares being "partially" visible. Here's some pseudo-code that makes a lot of assumptions:

```
from enum import Enum


class Direction(Enum):
    North = Vector2(0, -1)
    West = Vector2(-1, 0)
    South = Vector2(0, 1)
    East = Vector2(1, 0)


def get_visible_squares(player, squares):
    from operator import or_
    from functools import reduce

    def get_visible_squares_in_direction(direction):
        pos = player.position
        while squares[pos.y][pos.x]['walls'][direction] is not None:
            yield squares[pos.y][pos.x] # This square is visible.
            pos += direction.value # Add two vectors together.

    sets = [set(get_visibible_squares_in_direction(direction)) for direction in Direction]
    return reduce(or_, sets)
```

Basically, we iterate over all four directions (north, west, south and east), each time starting at the player's current position, and we start a while loop that tries to keep going in the given direction as long as it can until it hits a wall.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this. The problem is that your code only iterates through the squares in the 4 compass points, and I was trying to figure out how to do any square surrounding the character.

Comment: @chester Maybe you could update your question with some more pictures of what you expect the outcome to look like? For example, which squares should be visible when the player is at (2, 2), or (0, 0)? etc.

Comment: I edited the post to add more information. Maybe the solution to this problem would be to do what you did except with a vector for every square to cover every possible slope? Would I be right in guessing that? If so, how could I implement walls that might be in the way of a certain vector?

Comment: @chester Thanks for the updated images - I will take a look in a while.

Comment: @chester What framework are you using to render your game scene? Pygame? Tkinter? I would suggest also updating your question with a lot more code.

Comment: There is no game scene, it's a purely text-based game (a Discord bot). The only graphic/image that it ever sends is a map showing all of the squares, and the map doesn't change at all. What the visibility function would need to do is return a list of visible squares to describe using text what the character can see. I didn't include any more code because of the flexibility of how the squares and walls could be organized: I could format them in basically any way that could be useful, that's why I didn't show more of my work. Currently it looks like what I included in my question.